# TASM - debugger and compiling acting differently

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I am trying to run a loop that exits only if there was a legal input ( I am creating a card game). When compiling and entering an illegal input, the computer doesn't understand it as one and counts it as a legal one. However, while debugging it shows it is illegal and doesn't exit the loop.

The problem occurs upon entering a loop called valid press. This waits for the user to enter a valid input and doesn't exit unless it happens.

here is the loop:

```
Valid_Press:
        cmp [First_Round], 0
        je Skip_Plus_Two ; the first round variable is to determine if the first card on pile was discard card
        cmp [Last_Value], -4 ; check for +2 played last turn
        je Check_For_Two
        Skip_Plus_Two:
        mov [First_Round], 1 ; change it to one so it works only once
        call WaitForLeftClick ; first wait for left click
        Clicked:
        shr cx, 1 ; actual x
        ; check for draw 
        cmp dx, 70
        jb Maybe_Card
        cmp dx, 120
        ja Maybe_Card
        ; now cmp x
        cmp cx, 30
        jb Maybe_Card
        cmp cx, 60
        ja Maybe_Card
        ; if all conditions not reached, press was on picture
        jmp Draw_One_Card   
        
        Maybe_Card:
        push [Interval] ; interval
        push dx
        push cx
        call Is_On_Card ; check for press on card
            
        cmp ax, 0FFFFh ; the check
        je Press_Is_Card    
        xor bx, bx
        xor cx, cx
        xor dx, dx ; card was not valid, jmping to Valid_Press
        jmp Valid_Press ; input not card
            
        Press_Is_Card: 
        ; these calculaions are done to understand position of card pressed in hand based on his x cord and interval between cards  
        ;--------------------------------------------------------
        mov bx, cx ; x cordinate    
        sub bx, 11 ; distance
        mov ax, 18 ; width of card
        add ax, [Interval] ; distance of each card plus interval
        mov cx, ax ; distance of each card + interval
        mov ax, bx ; the actual X   
        div cl ; index in al
        xor ah, ah
        ;---------------------------------------------------------
        add si, ax ; si points to the index of the card that was pressed
        mov [Current_Index], al ; save index of card ( it is legal) 
        mov ax, [si] ; card that was pressed
        xor ah, ah
        mov bx, ax
        mov [Current_Value], bl ; value of card

        push si ; card offset   
        call CanPlayCard
        
        cmp cx, 5 ; the check
        je Card_Is_Right
        jmp Valid_Press ; card cannot be played, waiting for legal input
```

when debugging everything works fine and loop isn't exited but when running it is escaped.
Note: the game is some version of the UNO game and when trying to play in illegal card (for example, blue 1 on top of red three) it works when running and progresses to the next turn as if the input was legal,l. The debugger understands the card is illegal and doesn't continue forward.

Comment: Can you show the code and the illegal input that it's failing on?

Comment: @DarioPetrillo Yes, I will edit the post.

Comment: Perhaps a timing thing, or reading uninitialized memory that a debugger happens to modify?  Or user input behaves different when running under a debugger?   You haven't said which debugger you're using; perhaps turbo debugger?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I am using the turbo debugger to run my code. My mouse input does behave weird as well. After the first time calling a Mouse function ( it waits for left click and saves the position of click) it preserves the cordinates of the last calling. Also, I initialize all variables, setting them with some data.